# Не могу решить логическую задачу с последовательным выбором цифр

Tags: c

Не могу решить логическую задачу с последовательным выбором цифр.
Для каждого из набора цифр написать одиночный оператор, который будет печатать число из набора случайным образом:
"2, 4, 6, 8, 10"
"3, 5, 7, 9, 11"
"6, 10, 14, 18, 22"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{

  srand(time(NULL));
  int seed;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    seed = 1 + rand() % 10;
    if (seed % 2 == 0)
    printf("%d\n", seed);
  }

  printf("razdelitel\n");

  int m = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    seed = 1 + rand() % 11;
    m += 2;
    if (seed % m == 0)
    printf("%d\n", seed);
  }

  system("PAUSE");
}
```

Но это неверно, судя по всему.. Потому что каждое число которое будет генерироваться будет сравниваться с одним, процент выпадания будет очень мал.. А вот число которое бы делилось без остатка на порядок 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 вроде нету. Может кто-то подсказать, в каком направлении двигаться вообще, что то я застрял на этом..

Comment: Правильно ли я понял задачу:

> дан набор чисел, напечатать случайный поднабор данного набора

?

Comment: @VladD зря ответ удалили, код всегда лучше чем ничего...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: я понял, что неправильно понял условие задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в списках есть зависимость заранее известная или оговоренная, то достаточно получить случайное число в диапазоне, преобразовать его и получить случайное из набора.

```
 2*(1+rand()%5) - от 2 до 10
```

Если набор произвольный, то достаточно сделать из набора массив и выбирать случайным образом индекс в этом массиве.

Циклы при выборе значения не нужны.

Comment: Да я понял, изначально неправильно функцию использовал. Очень не корректно описано в некоторых местах(

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){

    int x;
    srand(time(NULL));    

    printf("-%d\n", 2*(1+rand()%5));
    if((x = (3+rand()%9))%2 != 0) printf("--%d\n", x);
    if((x = (3+rand()%9))%2 != 0) printf("---%d\n", x*2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]